# Как поменять статический массив на динамический?

Tags: массивы, c++

Здраствуйте! У меня есть рабочий код по работе с массивом, но я хочу его реализовать в динамический массив.

```
#include <iostream>
#define pause system("pause")
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int n=10;
    int M[n]={45,35,32,62,64,13,6,14,265,1};
    bool sort=true;
    int d,c;
    do
    {
        sort=false;
        for(int b=0; b < n-1; b++)
        {
            if(M[b] > M[b+1])
            {
                sort=true;
                c=M[b];
                M[b]=M[b+1];
                M[b+1]=c;
            }

        } 
    }while(sort == true);
    for(d=0; d < n; d++)
        cout << "Индекс массива " << d << " число: " << M[d] << "\n";

    pause;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста как его можно реализовать. Пишу на VC++ 2012.

Comment: а `std::vector<int>` нельзя использовать?

Comment: Замените конструкцию int* M[n]={...} на sdt::vector<int> M(n,0). Остальной код можно оставить без изменений.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#define pause system("pause")
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* m = new int[n];
    bool sort=true;
int d,c;
do
{
    sort=false;
    for(int b=0; b < n-1; b++)
    {
        if(M[b] > M[b+1])
        {
            sort=true;
            c=M[b];
            M[b]=M[b+1];
            M[b+1]=c;
        }

    } 
}while(sort == true);
for(d=0; d < n; d++)
    cout << "Индекс массива " << d << " число: " << M[d] << "\n";

pause;
```

}

Так же советую почитать про vector как раз для таких целей, которые вам нужны!

Comment: @Reocder А память освобождать кто будет?

Comment: @Reocder А элементы инициализировать кто будет?

Comment: а как освободить память?

Comment: @Max Adamchuk, о том как освободить память, вы можете прочитать в любой книжке по C++.

Comment: тогда для чего создан этот форум?

Comment: > тогда для чего создан этот форум?

для того чтобы помогать с тем чего нету в книгах! или что не так просто как new/delete